# Findstr using regular expression with space delimiter

Tags: batch-file

I used the findstr command using a space character as the delimiter to split a single line into two independent variables to manipulate.

I am unfortunately stuck progressing as I am not getting my expected results.

My "list.txt" file output looks like the list below.

*Note*: Each line had only one space character.

```
AAA 3,4,8,9
A13 5,7,8-10,13
AB3 12,34,55,57-60
```

Any help please.

```
@echo off
Set local enabledelayedexpansion
Set file = C:\users\list.txt
For /f "tokens=*, delims= " %%i in (%file%) do (
Set str = %%1
Set var1 = findstr /r "^[^ ]*" %str%
Set var2 = findstr /r "[^ ]*$" %str%
Echo %var1%.pdf
Echo %var2%.txt
)
```

Comment: I think it may help were you to also tell us what you want each variable to contain.

Comment: `tokens=1,2` will have `%%i` with first and `%%j` with second term.

Comment: a) `findstr` can't be used to return substrings. b) you can't set the output of a command to a variable this way. c) your `set` command's overall syntax is wrong.